# How to setup gradle JavaFX application in IntelliJ with Hibernate & JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gradle, intellij-idea

What is the best way to setup a new Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA version 2021.3.2?
Specifically, I am trying to setup JPA/Hibernate and am fairly new to this, but cannot seem to get it to work.

I have added the following in build.gradle, as per the IntelliJ guide:

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

    compileOnly('javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2')
    implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.5.Final')

}
```

When I try adding @Entity on a class, it is unable to compile as the Class is not recognised.

I also have the following persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
  <persistence-unit name="default">

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Entity comes from sping boot. You need to add it also. See project example at https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-gradle-example/ or find it somewhere on github.